# Decrypt EFS files

Tags: encryption, file-management, efs, file-attributes, decrypt

Here's my situation.

Was using EFS on my Vista laptop - had a backup of my certificate.

HD crashed...managed to recover some of my files (Encrypted) - but they "lost" the "Encrypted" attribute in the process.

I'm now on my new Windows 7 Enterprise laptop - imported my old Vista EFS certificate...I have my files on a USB drive and copied them over to my new drive (NTLM), but as I mentioned, Windows doesn't see them as being Encrypted...so I can't decrypt them.

Is there a way to either force the Encrypt attribute to be set, so that I'll then be able to decrypt them...or to force-decrypt them manually even though the system doesn't see the file as being encrypted?

Comment: NTLM is a network authentication protocol, not a filesystem. Did you mean NTFS?

Answer (score 11):

The EFS keys are kept in [**NTFS alternate data streams**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_streams_.28ADS.29), so if your USB drive was not formatted as an NTFS drive, the information would be lost.  **Backup programs often discard this information as well**.

You can check if the streams are still there using [Streams](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897440.aspx) or [ADS Spy](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/files/adsspy.php).  If they are no longer there, it will be impossible for you to recover your files.

As Windows does not flag the files as EFS encrypted, I think it is likely that you have lost the EFS keys in the streams.

Comment: I really like this answer because it provides **critically valuable** information.

Comment: For those who like FAR Manager, there is also a free and open-source plug-in (32-bit and 64-bit binaries are also available) that provides full access to NTFS alternate data streams (use the F11 key to access this plug-in after installing it):  http://code.google.com/p/farplug/#NTFS_File_Information

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately the ATTRIB command wasn't updated accordingly, so it cannot change this attribute.

There is a fantastic tool called FAR Manager which will allow you to change this and all other attributes:

FAR Manager (free and open source)
  http://www.farmanager.com/

Within this program, you simply navigate to the file or directory for which you wish to change the attribute(s) for, then press CTRL-A -- "Encrypted" is one of the attributes you can change in the dialogue that will appear:

[image]

Additionally, if you select a number of files first (press the Insert key on your keyboard to select files individually, or use the + or - keys to select or de-select groups of files based on a pattern), you can then press CTRL-A to change the attributes for all of them at once.

**HELPFUL TIP:**  When you're finished using this program, you can press F10 to exit.

For those who are interested, the **full list of editable attributes** are:

- Read only
- Archive
- Hidden
- System
- Compressed
- Encrypted
- Not indexed
- Sparse
- Temporary
- Offline
- Reparse point
- Virtual

...and other details that you can change include:

- Owner
- File modification date and time
- File creation date and time
- Last file access date and time