# Is it possible to remove the 'Are you sure you want to copy this file without its properties?'

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer

'Are you sure you want to copy this file without its properties?'
Yes, I'm sure, I'm certain... I never want to be asked again.

Once a month I need to copy small .mpg files [for in-store advertising screens] to a stack of SD cards, 50 or more, by hand.

It is but one more 'OK' to hit, but the sheer repetition gets a little tedious.

This earlier question - [Why am I ask “Are you sure you want to copy this file without its properties?” when copying files from NTFS to a FAT drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/403870/why-am-i-ask-are-you-sure-you-want-to-copy-this-file-without-its-properties-w) suggests Robocopy is capable of the task, but I'm not sure how much use a command line tool would be to me, as it's rare I need all copies identical, they are all usually individualised & I could see this making for a lot of typing, rather than a quick drag & drop.

Windows 7 SP1 Ultimate.

Additional thought -
Would setting up a small FAT partition to store these media file on get rid of the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be of use: [AlternateStreamView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/alternate_data_streams.html).

Never used it (and not affiliated to the author!) but it claims to be able to remove alternate data streams from NTFS files, which are the 'properties' the dialog refers to.

Comment: Done & done. So long as I remember to run it each time I get my new batch of content, all seems to be good.

Answer (score 0):

My crude but effective solution is a 7-line script. Whenever the dreaded dialog appears, the script presses Alt-A for "do this for all", and Alt-Y for "yes, lose the properties."

From the Github repository (https://github.com/joshwhitk/suppress-property-loss-dialog-during-copy-in-Windows-Explorer). Follow the 4 steps to compile and install.

This script runs in the background forever.  When this (or any AutoITS script) is running, you'll see a new icon in your tray. It's a small white tab with a green square on the left.

Obviously, this script is a crude workaround.  I would LOVE IT if someone figured out how to suppress those dialogs in the first place!

Please update Github with a text note if you do know of a better way (ie a registry setting).

cheers-

-Josh

Josh Whitkin 
Oakland, California 94611
whitkin.com