# Can the "Are you sure you want to copy this file without its properties?" halt be stopped when copying files?

Tags: windows, copy-paste, file-transfer, robocopy

When I copy data on my computer, I get a dialogue box with the message

> Are you sure you want to copy this file without its properties?

I know why this message pops up, but it does not make it any more welcome. Sometimes I copy massive amounts of data at once and I often leave my workstation to do something else while the copy is in progress. EVERY SINGLE TIME I come back and the copy has been interrupted about half way through with this stupid dialogue. I don't really want to have to babysit the computer the whole way through the copy.
Is there any way to remove it? I know that robocopy can do this but I'm not ideally looking for a command line solution.

Comment: What version of Windows? What have you already researched or tried?

Comment: Please include all of the details of your question in your question itself, and not just in the title.

Comment: I don't know why this question didn't get more love. It's the bane of my life too, I had to copy 150 videos to individual SD cards last weekend... same bloody message every time...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to remove the 'Are you sure you want to copy this file without its properties?'](https://superuser.com/questions/814312/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-are-you-sure-you-want-to-copy-this-file-without-it)